# My Magic Trackpad 2 starts getting jerky after around every 24h

Tags: magic-trackpad

The only way for me to stop this is by restarting my iMac when this happens. Why is this happening after many years and how can I fix it? I've scanned for malware and viruses and nothing is found. It's annoying because I have to stop what I'm doing and reboot. Then it works fine.

Comment: Do you have it permanently connected by a cable, or are you using Bluetooth?